# Microsoft Word: how to compare and edit 2 documents, without creating a 3rd one

Tags: microsoft-word, comparison, tracking, file-compare

I do proof reading on documents written by non-native English speakers. 
With text editors you get to compare 2 versions of the same document and you 
can edit either directly.

- In Microsoft Word, switching in and out **Track changes** mode is error-prone. You either make changes without setting the track mode and lose track of what was done, or you forget to remove it in the final version and get unwanted change bars in the pdf document.
- Using the Word **Compare** feature, what I see is the 2 documents in read-only mode, and a 3rd merged doc in track changes mode. That means managing 3 different files representing different versions of the same document, with the latest version using track changes. More chances of manipulation errors.

Is there any way in Word of comparing 2 documents, highlighting their differences and editing them directly, like in a text compare editor? Or have you solved this particular problem in another way, using MS Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the compare documents popup at the top you choose an Original document and a Revised document.

On the bottom right of the popup are 3 choices.

Show changes in:

- Original document
- Revised document
- New document

Only the 'New document' creates a third document.  Choose 'Original document' or 'Revised document' and the edits will show up as changes to the one you chose.